# How to restore stock firmware on HTC One mini

Tags: downgrade, stock-rom

I've bought [HTC One mini](http://www.gsmarena.com/htc_one_mini-5505.php) as my first smartphone and I would like to know: how do I revert to a version of Android that my phone came with?

Will I always have this possibility by default, or should I do take specific measures to this end? (e.g. back up my firmware, back up certificates or have my phone rooted)

Comment: Find the appropriate RUU and run it. You can find how to use RUU to restore on internet.

Comment: @Min When I'll do a Hard Reset, the system will restore to the latest version I upgraded to, is this right?

Comment: Yes. You will get the current version with all data cleared.